# Why is my PrimeReact dropdown component not detecting custom class styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, primereact

I'm using multiple Prime React dropdown components in my Project and want to style one of them in a different way. I've global styles for all of them in CSS to override the default one's. So for this specific dropdown, I tried applying new CSS styles using a custom class "custom-dropdown". But it's not even detecting the CSS styles inside nested in class "custom-dropdown". But, when applying without nested class, its working. (Sorry, Not able to provide entire code, so elaborated here. Thank you)

I tried this way in CSS, but I couldn't even see the styles while inspecting. Thank you

```
<Dropdown
      className="custom-dropdown"
      options={Days}
      value={selectedDay}
      onChange={(e) => {
      setSelectedDay(e.target.value);
     }}
/>
```

```
.custom-dropdown{ 
.p-dropdown-items {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.p-dropdown-items-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.p-dropdown-panel {
  max-width: 200px !important;
  min-width: 200px !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'panelClassName' can be used to add custom class for dropdown panel in PrimeReact dropdown component

```
<Dropdown
   panelClassName="custom-dropdown"
   options={Days}
   value={selectedDay}
   onChange={(e) => {
     setSelectedDay(e.target.value);
   }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues when styling. Please see working [**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-dropdown-example-forked-ncryw6?file=/src/App.js:759-944)

```
<Dropdown
   className="custom-dropdown"
   options={Days}
   value={selectedDay}
   onChange={(e) => {
     setSelectedDay(e.target.value);
   }}
 />
```

Also, you need may need to have the file extension `.scss` for your styles file.

Comment: Yes. I'm using scss file. But for some reason its not working in my case. No Typos or other mistakes. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I tried the same but its not detecting my class